# How to fix 'str' object has no attribute 'seek' error in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to implement this code https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-YOLOv3 ,and train it with my own dataset but i am running into the below error always while trying to validate it

```
---- Evaluating Model ----
Detecting objects:   0%|                                                                                                                                                              | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 160, in <module>
    batch_size=8,
  File "/home/harshvardhan/PyTorch-YOLOv3/test.py", line 36, in evaluate
    for batch_size, (imgs, targets) in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(dataloader, desc="Detecting objects")):
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1081, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 819, in __next__
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
AttributeError: Caught AttributeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/harshvardhan/PyTorch-YOLOv3/utils/datasets.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    img = transforms.ToTensor()(Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB'))
  File "/home/harshvardhan/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2772, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: It looks like your variable `fp` is somehow a string. And as the error says, a string object has no attribute "seek", and neither an attribute "read". Check your datatypes... Can not say more without the actual code snippet.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?